# $f:I\to \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable path. If $a\in I$ is an accumulation point of $f^{-1}(v)$, then $f'(a) = 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> I need to show that:
>
> Let $f:I\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a differentiable path. If $a\in I$ is an
>   accumulation point of the set $f^{-1}(v)$ for some $v\in
>  \mathbb{R}^n$, then $f'(a) = 0$

*ps: for a differentiable path we mean a function $f:I\subset \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that its cordinates are differentiable

If for a given $v$, it's set $f^{-1}(v)$ has an accumulation point, it means that there is more than one point $a$ such that $f(a) = v$, right? Because for definition, an accumulation point $a$ is a point $a$ not necessarily in $I$ (but here it's in $I$) such that every ball centered in $a$ also touches another point of $I$.

So I imagine that there is at least one more point different from $a$ such that $f(a) = v$, and this point, or points, are near $a$. I know that since they're infinitely close, the derivative at point $a$ would be $0$ because it's like the function were constant at that point, but I don't know how to write it. Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a$ is an accumulation point of $f^{-1}(v)$ implies that there exists a sequence $t_n\neq a$, $f(t_n)=v$ and  $lim_nt_n=a$. This implies that $f(a)=v$ since $f$ is continuous. $f'(a)=lim_{t\rightarrow a}{{f(t)-f(a)}\over{t-a}}=lim_n{{f(t_n)-f(a)}\over{t_n-a}}=0$.

Comment: Why the limit is 0?

Comment: Because the numerator of ${{f(t_n)-f(a)}\over {t_n-a}}$ is zero and its denominator is not zero.